# image transition

Tags: jquery, image

I am using the following dynamic code to get my gallery images:

```
        <section id="banner">
        {pyro:galleries:images slug="template-slider" limit="5"}
        <img src="{pyro:url:base}uploads/default/files/{name}" alt="{name}">
        {/pyro:galleries:images}
    </section>
```

I would like to create an image fade so it fades between all images in my div but I am not sure what the best way to go about it is due to being dynamic.

Do I get the id banner and img or just img?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Nivo-silder for the job